# split a dataframe on a factor and apply a function

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

In R, I want to split a data frame along a factor variable, and then apply a function to the data pertaining to each level of that variable.  I want to do all of this inside my function.  Somehow, the data aren't being split?

I don't understand all of the nuances of passing arguments to functions nested within other functions.  I had originally tried to do this with dplyr, but was unable to pass the arguments to dplyr nested within my function.

Here's my function:

```
 myFun <- function(dat, strat.var, PSU, var1){
     strata <- as.character(unique(dat[, strat.var]))
     N.h <- length(strata)
     sdat <- with(dat, split(dat, strat.var))
     fun1 <- function(x){ length(unique(x[, PSU])) }
     fun2  <- function(x){ sum(tapply(x[, var1], x[, PSU],  mean)) }
     ns <- sapply(sdat, fun1)
     mns <- sapply(sdat, fun2)
     dfx <- data.frame(cbind(stratum=strata, ns=ns, mns=mns))
     return(list(N.h = N.h, out=dfx))
 }
```

To demonstrate I use the warpbreaks data, but my actual data set has 8 levels of "strat.var" and nested within those are between 2 and 10 levels of "PSU".

```
    myFun(dat=warpbreaks, strat.var="wool", PSU="tension", var1="breaks")
   # $N.h
   # [1] 2

   # $out
   #   stratum ns              mns
   # 1       A  3 84.4444444444444
   # 2       B  3 84.4444444444444
```

But this isn't correct, because doing it by hand I get:

```
 sdat <- with(warpbreaks, split(warpbreaks, wool))
 fun1 <- function(x, PSU){ length(unique(x[, PSU])) }
 fun2 <- function(x, PSU, var1){ sum(tapply(x[, var1], x[, PSU], mean)) }
 sapply(sdat, fun1, PSU="tension") 
# A B 
# 3 3 
 sapply(sdat, fun2, PSU="tension", var1="breaks") 
#       A        B 
# 93.11111 75.77778
```

I'm using `sapply()` because of posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624999/writing-a-function-to-analyze-a-subset-within-a-dataframe) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790611/apply-t-test-on-many-columns-in-a-dataframe-split-by-factor).  And I'm not using `subset()` because I couldn't get it to work.  I'm aslo open to any suggestions using `dplyr()`.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Is the variable you're trying to compute the (numerical) mean of a factor (like warpbreaks$tension), or numerical? You can compute the numerical mean of a factor's levels, but it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: `as.character(unique(dat[, strat.var]))` is just an obfuscation for `labels(dat[, strat.var])` on your group_by variable. And the rest is obfuscated `group_by` and `summarize(newvar = mean(var))`

Comment: @smci, when I use `labels(dat[, strat.var])` I get a vector of 1:54, which is `nrow(warpbreaks)`.  What am I missing?

Comment: Doh! I meant `levels(dat[, strat.var])`  Levels, not labels.

Comment: I started implementing this in dplyr, but wanted you to confirm what you are doing, it does not seem to make any physical sense: first you `group_by(strat.var)`, then you hierarchically do another `group_by(PSU)`, and `summarize(mns = mean(var1))`, then you ungroup (just the split on PSU) and summarize with the sum of those individual means, then you ungroup again. Correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace

```
 sdat <- with(dat, split(dat, strat.var))
```

with

```
sdat <- split(dat, dat[strat.var])
```

in the `myFun`.

The previous code was not `splitting` as it was intended, instead you were getting the `sum` for the whole data, i.e.

```
sum(with(warpbreaks, tapply(breaks, tension, FUN=mean)))
#[1] 84.44444
```

Using the corrected `myFun`

```
myFun(warpbreaks, strat.var='wool', PSU='tension', var1='breaks')
#$N.h
#[1] 2

#$out
#  stratum ns              mns
#A       A  3 93.1111111111111
#B       B  3 75.7777777777778
```

You could also create a function using `dplyr` (you can fine-tune the below one)

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
myFun2 <- function(dat, strat.var, PSU, var1) {
   dat %>%
      mutate_(N.h = interp(~n_distinct(var),
               var = as.name(strat.var))) %>% 
      group_by_(.dots=strat.var) %>%
      mutate_(ns = interp(~n_distinct(var), var=as.name(PSU))) %>% 
      group_by_(.dots=PSU, add=TRUE) %>% 
      mutate_(mns=interp(~mean(var), var=as.name(var1))) %>%  
      select_(.dots= list(strat.var, 'ns', 'N.h', 'mns')) %>%
      unique() %>%
      group_by_(.dots=strat.var, 'ns', 'N.h') %>% 
      summarise(mns=sum(mns))                  
 }

myFun2(warpbreaks, 'wool', 'tension', 'breaks')
#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#Groups: ns, N.h

#  ns N.h wool      mns
#1  3   2    A 93.11111
#2  3   2    B 75.77778
```

Comment: The dplyr implementation is much cleaner than that, but first we need the OP to confirm this is really what they want to do, since it doesn't make physical sense to sum means calculated across a split by levels of a factor.

Comment: @smci It could be, I was just giving some ideas to the OP.  The main problem seems to be fixing his function.